# Can Blender make a timelapse video?

Tags: video

I was wondering if there is a script or addon that allows me to make timelapse videos of my blender projects?

For example, is it possible to add a camera to the scene which takes a quick image of the scene from that point of view every couple of seconds or moves?

Comment: Seems you are looking to make one of those 'Work-in-progress' time lapse where it shows the making of a model, correct?

Comment: This sounds like an interesting idea.. I think I'll try and write an addon which does this now :)

Comment: The problem will be the rendering... because it has to be quick enough and will comsume resources if you really render the scene. But I guess that isn't what OP wants anyways, right?

Comment: Hi guys, what they say below, they mean an image sequence creation through this screencast right? Let me know if you write this add-on. it would be great if it just recorded in solid view too.@gandalf3

Answer (score 11):

The built-in [Screencast](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/editors/info/screen_capture.html) tool is configurable such that you only get one frame every few seconds... or minutes.

From the docs:

> The default settings will generate a screencast consisting of a series of PNG images captured every 50 ms... The FPS for video Screencasts and time between each Screenshot for an image series Screencast can be set from the System panel of the User Preferences window.

If you're wanting a fixed-position shot of the current state of your model, though, this won't work. It'll just take a screenshot of whatever your Blender screen looks like at that moment.

Comment: so it is not possible to make a recording but only via image file? i can't find this built-in screencast feature.

Comment: I don't know if the built in Screencast feature has changed, but so far as I know, it does not produce a video file, but a sequence of images that you then compile into a video with Blender or another video editor.

Comment: thanks, unfortunately I can't find it anywhere. however you can select the camera from where to capture images? if I can find the tool, of course. lol

Comment: This feature was removed in Blender 2.8 :-( Got any alternatives?

Answer (score 8):

You can set **Frame Step** to skip frames by every certain number.
e.g.: If you want a 2x timelapse, then set the number to `2`.

[image]

You can also make it by tweaking the **Time Remapping** option, as shown in the same image. For example, **Old**=`100` and **New**=`50` for a 2x timelapse, However, you should also set the new End Frame by half, in order to offset the total number of render frames, because it will be doubled actually if you don't do it in such case, so this is not so recommended, personally speaking.

Furthermore, you can also have the Frame rate doubled, but that's obviously not a nice way either.

Comment: I think the OP wants to record a time-lapse animation from a camera while they work, rather than rendering or converting an existing video.