# Internal recording from camera 3D in Blender, is it possible?

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, camera, performance

by chance in blender is it possible to make an internal recording from a 3D camera located in position ''x'', for the performance of the activity in progress? He is then able to exploit the shot for possible compositional timelaps, from a certain angle without interruptions or turns of view, from an internal vision of the program. (obviously on / off
 ).
Thanks.

---

What I meant is if there is a method (not rendering) to record via a camera (and therefore from a certain location of your choice in the program's 3D space, [like a small GoPro in reality recording what happens from above] ) inside the 3d viewport. An alternative method instead of doing the normal screen recording, do it from within the program, recording at low resolution and only in Solid mode for example. Imagine a timelaps posted online recorded from within 3dviewport while creating something from scratch.

Comment: Hi! It is unclear what you are asking. Please elaborate what do you mean by "internal recording" as well as "internal vision" and how that should be triggered (re on/off). Suggest to [add images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) that 
might help us understand.

Comment: I updated the application also it was closed. tell me if you understand what I mean.  @brockmann

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/211890/record-a-timelapse-inside-blender-with-a-3d-camera-like-a-screensaver-inside-th

I asked another question from scratch hopefully more understandable.

Comment: Yeah, way better... so just a camera that is constantly recording a specific area of the workspace right?

Comment: yes, look they advised me to also see these questions but I didn't understand if they solve the question, because if I didn't understand wrong with screencast, a tool that I can't find, it should record a sequence of files every 50ms for example, but not I figured out where this tool is.
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/6659/can-blender-make-a-timelapse-video
https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/555/screen-recording-with-blender @brockmann

Comment: I guess the "screencast" tool is gone and was never ported to 2.8x, see the 2.79 manual: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/editors/info/screen_capture.html -> *"Screencasts will record your actions over time either as a video or sequence of image files"* However, the tool just records your screen and you'd like to record your scene right? If so, I think you'll have to write your own script which triggers an opengl rendering *(3DView > View > Viewport Render Image)* every x seconds or when saving the file, ideally using another machine so that you are not getting disturbed while working.

Comment: so there's no instrument that records from inside the Viewport, because to record the screen is easy, the question was to record from inside the Viewport 3d, with a certain angle while you're working. I'm gonna wait for someone to invent an add-on. I don't know Python that well. Lol

Comment: AFAIK there is nothing like that... would eat up a lot of machine power so I don't think this will be "invented" anytime soon.